# How do I play a mp3 using c# ... with no 3rd dll

Tags: c#, .net

/want to put a musical easter egg into my app

The SoundPlayer code below seems to only like mp3s :-(

```
       Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MyMp3, false);
        using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(stream))
        {
            player.PlaySync();
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Windows Multimedia API.

See this [page](http://dotnet.org.za/deon/articles/3057.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) only supports `.wav` files. You have two options:

1. Use another method, such as the one mentioned by Francis B
2. Convert the MP3 to a wav

As this is internal to your application, I'd convert it to a wav and use `SoundPlayer` to play it. The conversion will be a one-time process, so this is really the simplest solution.

Comment: WinLame is easy to use and quickly convert files between MP3/WAV/WMA